# $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery

I use datatables in jquery but not working. I can help. This is the script. Thanks! The #userList is a div thtat contain a table-striped table-condensed order-columns table-bordered. Thanks!

```
 $('#userList').DataTable({
    sortable: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'include/dades_customers.php',
        type: 'POST'
    },
    columns: [
        {"data": "CustName"},
        {"data": "Address1"},
        {"data": "Address2"},
        {"data": "City"},
        {"data": "PostCode"},
        {"data": "State"},
        {"data": "Country"},
        {"data": "Phone"},
        {"data": "Fax"},
        {"data": "Web"}
    ],
    lengthMenu: [ 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    //dom: '<"H"fi>rt<"F"lp><"clear">'

    dom: '<"top"fiB><"content"rt><"footer"lp><"clear">',
    buttons: [ 'colvis' ]

    /*footerCallback: function( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api();
        $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(
            api.column( 5 ).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
                return a + b;
            }, 0 )
        );
    }
    */  
});
```

Comment: Have you included all files? Also jquery?

Comment: yes! this is included

Comment: If it is not defined, you probably did not add appropriate plugin.

Comment: What is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

To use `DataTable` add the following references at the top of the page.Please note the order matters:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is where you say:

> The `#userList` is a `div`

I think the `#userList` can not be a `div` tag. It have to be the id of the `table` tag.